# Alert not presenting itself on either (click) or (tap) event in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Alert not presenting itself on either (click) or (tap) event in Ionic 2: When I try to click a list item in ionic and pass through the function, the function doesn't work, because I'm using native components, I can only test on the device which doesn't return runtime errors.

I'm not sure what the issue is, so any and all help would be appreciated.
here is my code below

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hotspot, HotspotNetwork } from '@ionic-native/hotspot';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 
'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
   selector: 'page-wifilist',
   templateUrl: 'wifilist.html',
})
export class WifilistPage {

  networks: any;
  wifiCredentials: {
  ssid: string,
  password: string
  }
  constructor(public hotspot: Hotspot, public navCtrl: NavController, 
public alertCtrl: AlertController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.hotspot.scanWifi().then((networks: Array<HotspotNetwork>) => {
      this.networks = networks;
    });
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad WifilistPage');
  }

  setWifiCredentials(ssid: string) { 
    console.log('working');
    this.wifiCredentials.ssid = ssid;
    let passwordAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Wifi Credentials',
      subTitle: 'Enter password for ' + this.wifiCredentials.ssid,
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'password',
          placeholder: 'password',
          type: 'password'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'cancel',
          role: 'cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'connect',
          handler: data => {
            this.wifiCredentials.password = data.password;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    passwordAlert.present();


    this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: this.wifiCredentials.ssid + ' ' + this.wifiCredentials.password,
      buttons: ['ok']
    }).present();
  }

}
```

and this is the code for the html:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
       <ion-title>
          Wifi Scanner
      </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let x of networks" (tap)='setWifiCredentials(x.SSID)'>
     <ion-avatar item-start>
     <img src="./assets/imgs/wifi-logo.png">
     </ion-avatar >
      <h1 (tap)='setWifiCredentials(x.SSID)'>{{x.SSID}}</h1>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: The tap event on the h1 tag was just to test, I'm aware of the double use of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're using single dots `' '` which refers to type string. You need to use double quotes `" "` which refers to the name of a variable or a method.

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let x of networks" (click)="setWifiCredentials(x.SSID)">
```

Comment: I tried your solution, unfortunately still no change.

Comment: I just tried my solution & it's working. There must be something wrong with your code somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in my .ts file, my wifiCredentials object hadn't been initialized prior to the method.